# preserve ascii in cshtml template

Tags: razor, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I want to display special characters like this one:
█

If I put this in a .cshtml file it's get screwed up through encoding/decoding.
How can I keep my character?

I already tried the following:

```
@Html.Raw("█")
@("█")
@Html.Raw(Server.HtmlEncode("█"))
```

Comment: What charset are you declaring?

Comment: UTF8 is added automatically - witch charset should I try to declare? This file http://minimum.apphb.com/readme.txt is also using UTF8 (by chrome guessing and displays perfectly!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it's HTML Entity:

(Decimal) `&#9608;`

(Hex) `&#x2588;`

Comment: True! But why can I paste the character in .txt and it displays, but if I paste it in .cshtml it gets f*cked up?

Comment: That's more likely to be a WebMatrix issue rather than a limitation of Razor or ASP.NET Web Pages. You can create .cshtml files in Notepad if you like. You should also consider how the user agent might behave. You are better off using the HTML entity.

Comment: I'm not using WebMatrix, so no bug on that part. But I would like to build boxes with these characters in my source file instead of using the HTML Entity http://brucejohnson.ca/SpecialCharacters.html#lines

Comment: Erm - you tagged WebMatrix. But I have just tested, and I can copy and paste your code into WebMatrix, so perhaps you should use it.

Comment: This github page https://github.com/PeterDeKeer/peterdekeer/blob/master/index.cshtml is auto deployed to appharbor http://minimum.apphb.com/ . I still see one 'block' and that is form using the HTML Entity

Comment: ╔═════════[ test ]══════════════╦═══════════╗
║                               ║           ║
║                               ║           ║
╠══════════════════╦════════════╬═══════════╣
║                  ║            ║           ║
║                  ║            ║           ║
╚══════════════════╩════════════╩═══════════╝

Answer (score 0):

Just solved my problem: The file itself was not encoded in UTF8+BOM!